# Understanding MD5 algorithm and how overflow doesn't occur

Tags: algorithm, md5

I have been reviewing the MD5 algorithm pseudo code on wikipedia, and I can't really seem to understand how an integer overflow doesn't occur.

Particularly this part:

```c
//Add this chunk's hash to result so far:
    a0 := a0 + A
    b0 := b0 + B
    c0 := c0 + C
    d0 := d0 + D
```

I would think eventually an integer overflow would occur, especially with large input. Wouldn't the value continue to swell and swell in size?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment at the top of the pseudocode on Wikipedia says:

```
//Note: All variables are unsigned 32 bit and wrap modulo 2^32 when calculating
```

So you need to make sure that unsigned 32 bit integers wrap modulo 2^32 on your platform. This is the case in many languages, for example C. Otherwise, you may need to perform the modulo manually.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by wrap?

Comment: @byteofthat You only look at the 32 low-order bits of the result, so when values exceed the maximum value it will wrap back to a low value. If you did calculations with wrapping modulo 10, then 7+5 would give you 2.